# Why is the rank of a matrix equal to the number of row-reduced nonzero rows?

Tags: linear-algebra

My textbook is slightly unclear. These are the excerpts and questions in bold:

[image]

And this next image is unclear to me. I can see why nullity is 2, but **why is the rank 2?**

[image]

I understand rank to be the number of vectors in the basis. **But why does row reducing the matrix lead to the rank?** My book doesn't really provide an explanation.

In this image, **why is the number of vectors in the basis $n-r$**? This sentence is confusing me:

> Solving for the first r variables in terms of the last n - r variables produces n - r vectors in the basis for the solution space, so the solution space has dimension n - r.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

"I understand rank to be the number of vectors in the basis."

Part of the reason you're confused is that your statements are ambiguous: the basis of *what*? The correct statement is that the rank is the number of vector in *a* basis *for the column space*. (There is a theorem that says the dimension of the column space is the space as the dimension of the row space.)

"But why does row reducing the matrix lead to the rank?"

Because row reduction preserves the dimension of the row space (which, by the theorem I quoted above, is the same as the dimension of the column space). In other words, two matrices that are row-equivalent have the same rank.

There is surely a theorem to this effect in your book.